# I Can't get a pic loaded onto my web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gif

I'm new to developing with C# and asp.net. I am trying to laod five images onto my web form I also need to do it code behind and not just drag and drop. I can't get them to work. I have tried:

```
dicePic[i] =  new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
//dicePic[0] = Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/1.gif"));
```

I also set the properties like this:

```
dicePic[0].ID = "Dice1";
dicePic[0].Style["position"] = "absolute";
dicePic[0].Style["top"] = "80px";
dicePic[0].Style["left"] = "80px";
dicePic[0].Visible = true;
dicePic[0].Width = 50;
dicePic[0].Height = 50;
dicePic[0].ImageUrl = "~/images/1.gif";//HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/1.gif");
dicePic[0].Controls.Add(dicePic[0]);
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please Could you show the error?

Comment: dicePic[0].Controls.Add(dicePic[0]); what this code does? You add your asp.net control to your same asp.net control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this line :`dicePic[0].Controls.Add(dicePic[0]);` by `this.Controls.Add(dicePic[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to a container in your page (or to the page itself).

if you are doing this inside a Page put

```
this.Controls.Add(dicePic[i]);
```

after

```
dicePic[i] =  new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
```